# Adobe flex layout redraw

Tags: apache-flex

this is a very basic question but I could not figure out.

My flex application gets some parameters from URL when the application opens for the first time(ex: layout=<1,2,3,4> ). Based on layout(1,2,3,4) value I have to change the layout. However the problem is the application is already drawn(Layout is initialized) by the time the control reaches the point where it reads the values from the URL.

I was wondering how can I redraw once  I read the values from URL. Some thing like refresh.

Or is there a better approach to my problem.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right approach but I fixed my problem my calling the function which is responsible for layout in applicationComplete.

It works great now.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be to wait for the URL to be parsed and then create your view based on that value.

This means that your Main.mxml should be empty when the application loads and when you parse the URL add your MainView to the application.

Something like
 - CreationComplete
 - ParseURL
 - AddMainViewElement

Answer (score 0):

According to the adobe documentation:

"After all components are created and drawn, the Application object dispatches an applicationComplete event. This is the last event dispatched during an application startup."

( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ee6.html)

so "applicationComplete" event fired after all the components created.